# How to make a proper edit route in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-router

Currently, my routes are something like this:

```
this.route('cards', function() {
  this.route('all');
  this.route('card', {path: ':id'});
  this.route('new');
});
```

I want to make an `edit` route for the cards. I'm hoping that making a route like `cards/1/edit` would be proper to make it editable. But I'm unsure about how to proceed with that. If I make a route like `cards/1/edit`, how can I show the edit form on that route and also send a PATCH request to the backend.

```
this.route('cards', function() {
  this.route('all');
  this.route('card', {path: ':id'}, function() {
    this.route('edit');
  });
  this.route('new');
});
```

However, if I make a simple route like `cards/edit/1`, I'm able to send data to the backend but then it would have something like the following:

```
this.route('cards', function() {
  this.route('all');
  this.route('card', {path: ':id'});
  this.route('new');
  this.route('edit', {path: ':id'});
});
```

This throws error stating that `cards/card` is not a route.

Comment: I recommend reading up a bit at https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments. Might help clear up some of your confusion.

Comment: thank you for that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the actual route which i used:

```
this.route('cards', function() {
  this.route('all');
  this.route('card', {path: '/:card_id'}, function() {
    this.route('edit');
  });
  this.route('new');
});
```

And I'm going to the edit route (`cards/1/edit`) to modify the card.

Thanks to @Visualjeff

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've done in the past:

```
this.route('cards', function() { 
  //An index route for cards is implied.
  this.route('add', {path: '/add'});
  this.route('update', {path: '/update/:id'});
});
```

Corresponding urls (starting with the implied cards/index.hbs) would be:

- http://localhost:4200/cards
- http://localhost:4200/cards/add
- http://localhost:4200/cards/update/1

Hope this helps,

Jeff

Comment: then how do you show your individual card? i'm assuming that the url `/cards` will show all the cards and `/cards/add` is for adding a new card and `/cards/update/1` is for updating. what if you want to show an individual card like `/cards/1`?

Comment: Everything you stated above is correct.  A user could drill down from the list of cards to a specific card by going to the update page (cards/update/1).  If they're authorized or allowed to update them provide access to update otherwise show the data (without the ability to update).  Read only fields, No update button.

Comment: You mean that the show and edit route should be same with the authorized users having the ability to update the details. Right?

Comment: Yes.  BTW, The update page could also include a delete button/delete action and if the user was authorized they could also delete a specific record.  If they we're not authorized then they wouldn't see the delete button.  Just a suggestion.

Comment: i implemented a slightly modified version of this.